# Form Popups and interaction

Tags: vb.net, forms

How can I get Visual Basic to open another form using code? I have attempted to google the solution several times and never found anything that works.

Also, do VB forms share variables? Is there any way for one form to send data to another form?

I know this should be really simple, but I just cannot figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forms are nothing but classes so by creating public methods, properties or variables you already have possibilities to communicate between them. You can create new forms like you create objects

```
Dim Frm As New MyNiceForm
```

and then show them with `.Show` or `.ShowDialog`.